# How to detect user allowed the location permission for once?

Tags: ios, swift

When I granted the permission "Allow Once", `didChangeAuthorization` of `CLLocationManagerDelegate` was receiving the `.authorizedWhenInUse` status, but there is no such status for **AllowOnce**. How can I know that user didn’t choose the correct option?

[permission request popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9d0I.jpg), [types of location status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b05UP.png)

Comment: If you choose allow once, it’s the same permission as whenInUse.  You will just be promoted again next time permission is requested

Comment: @valosip you meant prompted

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, thanks for catching that.  Too late to edit.

Comment: @valosip you're right, it will be prompted again next time. But, I cannot be able to request for always without 'When In Use' permission has truly granted. The prompt for always permission isn’t coming up, even though I got the same permission with the once option.

Comment: @YeLinAung did you ever figure out on how to solve for this? I am also struggeling with the same issue right now.